# What is considered the current main line for Black against the Smith-Morra gambit?

Tags: opening, smith-morra-gambit

I am referring to main lines where the pawn sacrifice is accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Most reference books will give the main line as

```
1. e4 c5 2. d4 cxd4 3. c3 dxc3 4. Nxc3 Nc6 5.Bc4 e6 6.Nf3 d6 7.0-0 Nf6 8.Qe2 0-0 9.Rd1 e5
```

Followed by either 10.Be3, 10.h3, 10.Bg5, 10.a3 or even 10.b4.

They usually evaluate this 'main line' as a dynamic equality.

Repertoire books often offer other ideas for Black (with...g6, or ...Ne7, or ...Bb4, or ...a6 and ...b5, or 3..e5 or refusing the gambit right away).

```
[fen ""]    
1. e4 c5 2. d4 cxd4 3. c3 dxc3 4. Nxc3 Nc6 5.Bc4 e6 6.Nf3 d6 7.O-O Nf6 8.Qe2 Be7 9.Rd1 e5
```

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that in ECO, but I thought that the "old" mainline; from recent trends I thought it might have been replaced.